# ModalPopup for dynamic objects

Tags: asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender, ajaxcontroltoolkit

In my ASP.net website I have **dynamically** created a ImageButton named **"Logout**". Is it possible to use the ID of this Logout button as the **TargetControlID** for the ModalPopup(AJAX).

In HTML Page :

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="LogoutModal" runat="server">
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

In Serverside :

```
LogoutModal.TargetControlID = "OutBut"; //  OutBut is the ID of Dynamically created imagebutton
LogoutModal.PopupControlID = "Panel1";

LogoutModal.show(); // is it correct ?
```

Comment: Yes you can use it but it depends upon when you will create a LogOut button? If you will create a button in Page_Load() then I think it should works.

Comment: Thnkx for your support Omair... Yes, Iam creating the button during the Page_Load but am adding that button in the **Calendar's DayRender event**.